# INSERT with a condition

Tags: mysql

I have this table `pageview`

```
 id    |   visitor   |   id_realestate  |   time
 -----------------------------------------------
```

I want the record to be inserted if only the last `time` is 30 mins old at least for that particular  `id_realestate` which has been checked by that particular `visitor`

### update

to make it clearer. If I have this data ready to be inserted in the table

```
visitor:"axax"
id_realestate:120
time:NOW()
```

these value should be inserted if only the last record with these values `visitor:"axax"` & `id_realestate:120` is older than 30 minutes (by checking the field `time` for the last record of the two values I mentioned and compare it with `NOW()` if the difference is greater than 30 minutes. if so then the data should be inserted)

### update

I have this these data now. as you can see the time field contains a value from yesterday so any new data should be inserted:

[image]

I used this query as suggested by **anubhava** but nothing happened ( no new record added/ no errors)

```
$query='insert into pageview
select "q17872745t", 150, now() 
from pageview a
where id_realestate=150 and DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) > (
  select max(time) from pageview b where a.id_realestate=b.id_realestate AND   a.visitor=b.visitor
)';
```

### update

I modified the query to the following and it's working **BUT** *It compares with every `time` **if the latest time is 30 mint old** and accordingly it inserts a record( meaning it doubles the records)*. so if I have two records with same `visitor` and `id_realestate` it will compare with these two records if the `time` in both is 30 minutes old then it inserts 2 identical records whereas it should insert one record.

```
      $query='insert into pageview (visitor,id_realestate,time)
      select "q17872745t", 150, now() 
         from pageview a
         where id_realestate=150 and DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) > (
            select max(time) from pageview b where a.id_realestate=b.id_realestate AND a.visitor=b.visitor
      )';
```

### update: [solved]

I added `LIMIT 1` at the end of the above query, now it's working as it should. here is the final query:

```
      $query='insert into pageview (visitor,id_realestate,time)
      select "q17872745t", 150, now() 
         from pageview a
         where id_realestate=150 and DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) > (
            select max(time) from pageview b where a.id_realestate=b.id_realestate AND a.visitor=b.visitor
      ) LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a very clear question but you can use a query like this: (**untested**)

```
insert into pageview
  select 15, 'A VISITOR', 10, now() 
  from pageview a
  where id_realestate=10 and DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) > (
      select max(news_release) from pageview b where a.id_realestate=b.id_realestate
  );
```

Comment: for those who want a tested working query as I described it. see the last update in my question. thanks anubhava.