# returning a specified value if there are no results

Tags: mysql

I have this query here:

```
  $query='insert into pageview (visitor,id_realestate,time)
  select "q17872745t", 150, now() 
     from pageview a
     where DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) > (
        select max(time) from pageview b where a.id_realestate=b.id_realestate AND a.visitor=b.visitor
  ) LIMIT 1';
```

I want this part:

```
  select max(time) from pageview b where a.id_realestate=b.id_realestate AND a.visitor=b.visitor
```

to return a **date/time** which is **now() minus 40 minutes** *if* there are *no results*

Comment: What are trying to do? Why are you getting table `pageview` twice? Tell us what you need to insert and we can refactor your query correctly

Comment: @Marco see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251082/insert-with-a-condition/9251278#9251278
I want now to still insert the data if the combination (visitor,value) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `MAX(time)` in an [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) clause.

```
IFNULL(MAX(time), NOW() - INTERVAL 40 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is correct, simply wrap your current query in another query and check to see if the value is null like so:

select IFNULL( select max(time) 
               from pageview b 
               where a.id_realestate=b.id_realestate 
                  AND a.visitor=b.visitor, DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTES) );

In the above query, I've wrapped your query using max() as a subquery, and if the value returned is null, return a value using DATE_SUB to subtract 30 minutes from now().